# Закругление рамки

Tags: html, css

Я хочу закруглить рамку, но не получается пишу в 
*style.css*
.Ramka

```
{
  border-radius:6px;
}
```

а чтоб прикрепить к рамке пишу вот такой скрипт

```
<div class="Ramka">
<table border="1" width="500" bgcolor="#7F7F7F" align="center" bordercolor="black" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
</div>
```

Comment: Если в `.Ramka` нет `padding`, то рамка таблицы будет перекрывать заокруглённые уголки блока, содержащего эту таблицу.

Answer (score 3):

Привет. Посоветую в стилях прописать `overflow` и `display`, т.е. примерно получиться должно так:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Border-Radius</title>
<style>
.ramka
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ramka">
<table border="0" width="100" bgcolor="#7F7F7F" align="center" bordercolor="black" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td>asdasdasdsad</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Надеюсь, это поможет решить ваш вопрос. :)

Comment: надеюсь)))